# задание массива символов

Tags: c, строки

```
char arr[5];
int a;
scanf("%4s", arr);
scanf("%d", a);
```

в консольной программе, при вводе в массив свыше 4 символов, они уходят в переменную 'a' если это были числа, то излишек после первых 4 уходит в 'a' если же это были символы, то переменная остается без изменений... но считывание с консоли пропускается.
какую проверку добавить в считывание строки, чтобы избежать этого или быть может путь обхода?

Comment: Избежать чего именно? Что должно "уходить в a", а что не должно? Опишите вменяемо требуемое поведение.

Comment: 1. Пользователь вводит массив. 2. Программа проверяет, что введённый пользователем массив не превышает допустимое количество символов, излишек отбрасывается к примеру. 3. вывожу фразу "printf("Введите а");" 4. пользователь вводит значение. А еще объясните, как переводить строку в  комментариях? <br/> не сработал)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если нужно ввести в программу строку, длина которой наперёд не известна, то рекомендуется действовать так:

- Заводим в программе буфер, размером заведомо больше длины строки. Например - 1024
- Вводим строку с клавиатуры с помощью вызова *fgets*
- Проверяем длину введённой строки
- Если с длиной всё нормально - копируем её в необходимую переменную.
- Если длина строки явно "не катит" - печатаем сообщение об ошибки и повторяем ввод.

Comment: Ну, я имел ввиду погрешность на "дурака", типо какой-нибудь эпилептик головой об клавиатуру побился, вбил 1025 символов и вот, важная переменная расчета полета Илона Маска на Марс частично затерта... хотя, это консольная утилитка и в десктопных будет больше возможностей ограничить вводимые значения.
 Просто для общего развития хотелось узнать о возможности программно сделать более жесткую проверку...

Comment: @Briarey_ *вбил 1025 символов* стандартная функция *fgets* как раз и предотвращает такую ситуацию. У неё парамер задаёт максимально допустимую длину вводимой строк. Больше этого она НЕ введёт.

Comment: спасибо, попробую)